# Adjusting content to layout frame

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I just started learning how to develop apps for android. I have a seamingly easy question but I couldn't find an answer to it.

I'm trying to do the opposite of what wrap-content does (in the context of an image button).
I want my content to adjust to the frame of the button, whereas wrap-content matches the frame to the content.

Is there a way to do that? It sounds easy enough but I couldn't figure out how. Thanks in advance!

EDIT : I think I've expressed myself poorly, sorry.

What I really want is to be able to resize the frame of my image button, with its content adjusting by itself to the frame, instead of having the button crop around a static picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use match_parent

From [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html):

> Match Parent: Sets the dimension to match that of the parent element. Added in API Level 8 to deprecate fill_parent.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
```